# How to handle mobile web Safari Deny/ Allow popup?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, mobile-safari, safaridriver

I am trying to write automated tests using C# Selenium to cover a portion of an application. The scenario is that I reach a page (on the mobile web version of a site, using a safari browser on a real device via Browserstack) and there is a button on the page that will take me to another tab/ external site that I would like to go to. When I click on the button on the page, a safari alert popup shows that I have to Deny or Allow. In this case I want to allow it and move on to the next tab.

I have allowed safari popups for my WebDriver like this:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.SetCapability("safariAllowPopups", "true");
```

The problem, is that when I click on the button, the alert popup shows which is expected, but then I get an error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.UnhandledAlertException : A modal dialog was open, blocking this operation
```

The error is happening on the element I am trying to click, which doesn't make much sense. Because I just clicked that button in order to get the alert popup to show. Since it errors here, I can't select allow, or let the WebDriver handle it to allow the popup. It just fails here. This is the code I am trying to execute:

```
private readonly exampleButton = By.XPath("//div[@id='buttonContainer']//img[@id='buttonImage']");

//I was told by a browserstack support that I need to switch the WebDriver context to Native App in order to interact with the alert popup
driver.SwitchTo().WithContext("NATIVE_APP");
driver.FindElement(exampleButton).Click(); //The test fails here with the exception noted above

//I have tried this to allow the popup, but of course the code doesn't reach here
IAlert popup = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
popup.Accept();

//I have also tried this to allow the popup, but of course the code doesn't reach here
IWebElement ll = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Allow"));
ll.Click();

//Switch back to normal context
driver.SwitchTo().WithContext("WEB_VIEW");
```

[Image of popup I modal that is blocking button operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFOvJ.png)

So why in the world is the button that was clicked in order to show the alert popup, being blocked from operating by the very modal it opened?!